# React+Javascript:-Component will update is getting called too many times causing my application to crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, mobx

```js
 componentWillUpdate() {
  
  //Axios GET method for getting all the trades

  //Adding data of db into mobx store/or syncing data of db and store
  axios.get(`http://localhost:8091/trade`)
   .then(res => {
    this.props.store.arr = res.data;
   })

 }
```

This piece of code causing my browser to crash, my laptop to not responding.

Actually, whenever i was trying to delete the row of table containing trade by click of button then the trade was deleted but it took the need of refresh to see that the trade is deleted.

This was because my mobx store and db were not in sync.So as soon i refresh the (REST api) controller updates data in my mobx store.After this i can see that trade is deleted.

So in order to remove the need of refresh i thought to use component will update method.Within that method i tried to sync mobx store with controller data (db data).It worked but it caused the browser to take more than 2.5 gb of memory &  at this point all the running applications starts getting crashed also.

So what is the good way to achieve the desired result?

Note i don't know why ***component will update*** is getting called too many times.
But i can verify the it because i can see the selection statements(of database) in spring (my server which is sending data to controller ).

Putting the above code inside ***component did mount*** is not removing the need of refresh but it is not causing the browser to crash also.

Comment: Never mutate `this.props` yourself. We need more information about your code how you can write it so you can avoid this pattern.

Comment: I am just taking the data from controller and putting it into mobx store.The code has different components and the no of code lines is also large.Which piece of information of code you will need ?

Comment: @ShivendraGupta, your component should represent the data, not fetch it. Move data manipulation logic to some other class, and subscribe to it. There are plenty of patterns available, 30 seconds of googling leads to: https://codeutopia.net/blog/2016/02/01/react-application-data-flow-where-and-how-to-store-your-data/. I suggest you to spend an hour on reading about the design: it will help you write manageable code with clear separation of concerns, that should boost your productivity significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing this type of operation in this lifecycle hook. You should use [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) instead for any remote calls that need to happen. However since you are using mobx, you really should not be having these problems as they handle these type of problems for you with the observer pattern. Please read: https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html to get up to speed and you should have no issues at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your component's `props` or `state` is causing it to update often, which is causing a lot of calls to the api. Your best bet would be to find out what is causing those updates and use `nextState` and `nextProps` arguments supplied to `componentWillUpdate` to check and send an api call only when needed. Something like:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {
   if (nextProps.needToGetApi !== this.props.needToGetApi) {
     //Axios GET here, so that unrelated prop/state change does not cause this to run
   }
}
```

Hint: Add a breakpoint in `componentWillUpdate` and see what `props` or `state` mutations are happening on each call.